# Using os.listdir() to write file names in TXT but uncompleted

Tags: python, file

I am trying to write all the file names, including their paths, in a folder to a text file. what I am doing is below:

```
import os

BASEDIR = r"C:\project 111"

aa = os.listdir(BASEDIR)

text_file = open(os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'all files.txt'), "w")

for b in aa:
    c = os.path.join(BASEDIR, b)
    text_file.write(c)
    text_file.write('\n')

list_open = open(os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'all files.txt'))
read_list = list_open.read()
line_in_list = read_list.split('\n')
number_of_files = sum(1 for line in open(os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'all files.txt')))

print number_of_files
```

the problem is that, it doesn't write all the wanted files to the text file. the actual number of files is more than 500 however it only writes 379 lines. and the last line in the text file is uncompleted.

what's the cause of the problem, and how can I correct it? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### using context managers (`with` keyword)

for reference:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing
- http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

and of course the official doc: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

> It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is also much shorter than writing equivalent `try`-`finally` blocks:

```
>>> with open('workfile', 'r') as f:
...     read_data = f.read()
>>> f.closed
True
```

### the problem is not close()

The problem isn't that `close()` magically adds the data to the file. The problem is that most operating systems are intelligent and have different levels/layers of buffers (or the problem is that not everyone reads the docs or goes to a CS course). In order for your data to reach the disk, you need to flush the buffers. This is done with [`file.flush()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=flush#file.flush). `close()` calls `flush()`.

Using the context manager (`with open...`) hides that complexity; so it is safer for most use cases to stick with that construct.

Comment: thanks, dnozay, and the details. it's very difficult to choose the best from all the answers..

Answer (score 3):

After opening a file with the `open` function, you should always close it when you're done, otherwise the behavior can be unpredictable.

```
text_file.close()
list_open.close()
```

### Update

A better way to go about doing this is to use context managers (i.e. the `with-as` statement). Then you don't have to worry about closing them at all; the context manager does it for you as soon as it goes out of scope!

```
with open(os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'all files.txt'), "w") as text_file:
    for b in aa:
        c = os.path.join(BASEDIR, b)
        text_file.write(c)
        text_file.write('\n')

with open(os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'all files.txt')) as list_open:
    read_list = list_open.read()

line_in_list = read_list.split('\n')

with open(os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'all files.txt') as allfiles:
    number_of_files = sum(1 for line in allfiles))

print number_of_files
```

Here's a nice introduction to context managers: https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-python-mark-lutz-4th/chapter-33/withas-context-managers

Comment: This is a great time to talk about using context managers for file access!

Comment: twasbrillig, hope you don't mind I choose the other one with more explanations for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, a better recommend solution is to use `with` statement to open/write a file
`with` statement will auto call `close()` when executing exist the block
 :

```
with  open(os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'all files.txt'), "w") as f:
    for b in aa:
        c = os.path.join(BASEDIR, b) 
        f.write(c + "\n")
```

for a quick fix is adding close() call to file object:

```
for b in aa:
    c = os.path.join(BASEDIR, b)
    text_file.write(c)
    text_file.write('\n')

// pls add this line
text_file.close()

list_open = open(os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'all files.txt'))
```